# Proving equality false using proof by contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Question:

Does there exist **natural numbers** $a,b$ such that $ a^2-b^2\ =\ 19 $? If yes find all pairs of a,b and show how you found them , if you say no prove it.

My thinking:

I think proof by contradiction would be the best technique to solve this question. If we assume there exist such x and y natural numbers, how can we show a contradiction? I am not quite sure how to use proof by contradiction to solve the question.

Thanks

Comment: $2^2-1^2=3$, $3^2-2^2=5$, $4^2-3^2=7,\ldots$

Comment: Are you sure that "doesn't exist natural numbers  ... "$$a=10,b=9 \\ a^2-b^2=100-81=19$$

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. Please see updated version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$a^2-b^2
= (a-b)(a+b)$.

How many ways can 19 be factored?

Comment: If a-b = 1 and a+b = 19 or if a-b = 19 and a+b = 1

Comment: Now solve for a and b.

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel a and b are natural numbers. Thus $a-b=19,a+b=1$ has no solution.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by no solution?

Comment: You have to check the two cases where $a-b = 1$, or $a-b = 19$. The expression $(a+b)(a-b)$ could equal $(1)(19)$ or $(19)(1)$, which yield two different results.

Comment: So there does exist such natural numbers?

Comment: Do I have to use proof by contradiction?

Comment: The solution exists, where a = 10, and b = 9.

Comment: @Josh Mitikitzel I'm sorry to say that if you can't infer such basic information from a proof, you have to work much harder to understand how others use mathematical reasoning in a proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60219/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-josh-mitkitzel).

Comment: @TobyMak :" Sorry, what do you mean by no solution?" The smallest natural number is 1. Set $a=b=1$ then $1+1>1$

Comment: What does the smallest natural number have to do with a set of simultaneous equations?

Comment: I meant $a + b =19$ in my post.

Comment: @TobyMak You can exclude the equation system $a−b=19,a+b=1$ very easily because it can be seen very easily that $a+b=1$ has no solution for natural numbers.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @martycohen 19 can be factored only one way since it's a prime number right?

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2-b^2=19 \\(a+b)(a-b)=19\times 1 \\so \\(1) \begin{cases}a-b=1 \\a+b=19\end{cases}\\
(2)\begin{cases}a-b=19 \\a+b=1\end{cases}\\$$solve them 
$$(1) \to 2a=20 \to a=10 \\10-b=1 \to b=9 \checkmark \\(2) \to 2a=20 \to a=10 \\10+b=1 \to b=-10 \space (not-natural) $$

Comment: What is the final conclusion of the question?

Comment: Case (1) works but Case (2) doesn't because $b$ is not a natural number.

Comment: So, there does exist such natural numbers?

Comment: I don't have to prove that there doesn't exist such natural numbers?

Comment: What can I conclude from Case(2) ?

Comment: case (1) shows that exist at least a solution $\in N  \\$  but case (2) is not a solution because of  "natural numbers" .so final conclusion is :there is natural numbers solution for equation $(a,b)=(10,9)$

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to approach the question is to consider the difference of consecutive squares $$(x+1)^2 - x^2.$$

This simplifies to $(x^2 + 2x + 1) - x^2$, or $2x + 1$. The remaining step is to solve the expression for $19$ i.e $2x + 1 = 19$, so $x = 9$.

Therefore the two numbers are $9+1$ and $9$, or $10, 9$. Verifying by substitution gives $10^2 -9^2$ which is $19$.

Comment: Credit to @Lord Shark the Unknown - this is an expanded version of his comment as a full answer.